# Does the plural include the singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, logic

Does the plural include the singular? And if so, in what sort of cases?

This question has arisen because of the example sentence below.

Amendment shall be permitted only in cases of:
1.  deletion of claims
2.  correction of error

My co-worker, who is not a native speaker of English, insists that if only one error is corrected (or if only one claim is deleted), then amendment will not be permitted. Is this the necessary interpretation?

Is there a specific name for this issue? And if plural does include the singular, what are some less legalistic examples that can be used to explain that the plural form is not necessarily, well, plural?

Comment: If amendments were only permitted if both cases were satisfied, I would expect it to say "in cases of deletion of claim AND correction of error." In your example can both conditions actually be met simultaneously?  I'm confused by your title and your question and example.  Perhaps you can try explaining it better.

Comment: This sounds like something you need a lawyer for.

Comment: Since "case" is plural, it's talking about two cases in which amendment is permitted. Your co-worker's interpretation makes no sense because with that interpretation, there would only be one case.

Comment: Try the verb to amend and forget amendment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues that seem to be in play.

In most cases, a reference to plurals in rules also includes the singular. And vice versa.

> In the event of errors, accommodation will be made.

While the plural is used, most readers would believe that this applied to a single error as well as multiple errors.  Similarly

> In the event of error, accommodation will be made.

It means the same thing.

Sometimes, to make clear that both singular and plural circumstances apply, parenthetical plurals are used.

> In the event of error(s), accommodation will be made.

This makes it explicit that both singular and plural problems will be adjusted for.

I am not aware of a term that names this characteristic (or conundrum).

As you have suggested, this is a problem often faced in legal drafting (which you wish to avoid).  To ensure clarity, many contracts say something that means "plural words can cover singular events and singular words can cover plural events."

To convey this simply you could say

> Amendment shall be permitted only in cases of: 1. deletion of *one or more* claims 2. correction of *one or more errors*.

Your example also raises another issue.  It lists two conditions:

> 1. deletion of claims 2. correction of error

There is some ambiguity as to whether these conditions are *conjunctive* or *disjunctive* as written. Does it mean

> when there is both  1. deletion of one or more claims ***AND***  2. correction of one or more errors

or does it mean

> when there is either  1. deletion of one or more claims ***OR***  2. correction of one or more errors, ***BUT NOT BOTH***

or does it mean

> when there is either  1. deletion of one or more claims ***OR***  2. correction of one or more errors, ***OR BOTH***

You need to clarify whether you mean

- 1. AND 2.
- 1. BUT NOT 2.
- 1. AND/OR 2.

Answer (score 6):

Your co-worker is misinterpreting the statement.

The "*error*" is in the interpretation of the word *error*

[***Error***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/error) can mean:

> a mistake or inaccuracy

but it can also mean

> the condition of deviating from accuracy or correctness

The first is countable the second is not.  I  believe the intention is to say, that amendments are only allowed in 2 situations, either when claims are being deleted or when the document is found to be in error (second definition above).

Of course as @tchrist says, only a lawyer can tell you whether he'd be willing to defend that interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

For knowing true meaning of words ordinary, plain and grammatical meaning is to be used as a matter of principal unless plain meaning render an absurd meaning. in the above example words / sentence to be understood according to the intention of the maker of the sentence; and in the absence of clear intention of the maker than effects to be given to the plain words used; in case of singular, consequential result must be taken in singular form and in case of plural the result shall be taken in plural. we cannot by our personal whims and presumptions change the complexion of the sentence, unnecessarily.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).